# Access function from other component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I created a topbar menu thats needs access to a react component. Inside the topbar file I do not render the other components, but would like to access a function inside one of the components I use.

The project structure looks like this:

```
Header Component
TopBar Component
LayoutWrapper Component <-- Here I render other components
  CustomerDetails Component <-- Here sits the functon I want to call.
```

This is the TopBar File:

```
class AdminTopbar extends Component   {
  renderTopMenu() {

    ...

    if (currentPage.projects || currentPage.customers || currentPage.activities) {
        return(
            <nav>
                ...

                <li>
                    // Function needs to be called here
                    {menuPageType == null ? null : <button onClick={updateActivityCardDetails.bind(this)}>Archiveren</button>}

                </li>
            </nav>
        );          
    }`enter code here`
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="topbar clear">

        ...

        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(AdminTopbar);
```

ActivityCardDetails file where the function sits:

```
class ActivityCardDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // set page title
    document.title = 'Strippenkaarten overzicht';
  }

  updateActivityCardDetails() {

  }
}
```

I found some posts about refs to the parent but I don't have a nested structure between those files.

As a recap: On the TopBar components, which is a separate components without any relations, I would like to call the updateActivityCard method that sits in the ActvityCardDetails components.

Comment: Do you use redux or flux?

Comment: You can use ref to get the instance of child.
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Swapnil I do not use any of those.

Answer (score 2):

React has recently(ish added the context API ) https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

You'd probably be best off breaking the function out of the component because it's used by different components who aren't strictly hierarchically related. Then just use context to access it from each component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your whole structure with a wrapper component and follow the instruction given on each line below:

```
Wrapper Component <-- Here place a state and a custom function that can set a callbackFunction to its state e.g. myFunc = (callback) => this.setState({updateFunction: callback}) 
  Header Component
  TopBar Component <-- Pass the Wrapper Component's state here through props, like state={this.state}
  LayoutWrapper Component <-- Pass the Wrapper Component's custom function here through props
    CustomerDetails Component <-- Pass the Wrapper Component's custom function here through its parent's props, and call it like 'this.props.myFunc(this.yourInnerUpdateFunction)' on DidMount
```

Once you're done with this, you should be able to call the updateFunction() from your TopBar component through 'this.props.state.updateFunction()'

P.S. It's not an ideal approach, but it can get the job done if your app isn't too heavy. Hope this helps.